# Remove all strings from list of strings and integers

Tags: jython

You are given:
list1 = [2, "berry", "joe", 3, 5, 4, 10, "happy", "sad"]

want to return
[2, 3, 5, 4, 10]

Is it possible to remove just the strings from the list?

Comment: Loop through the list and check for alphabets...

Answer (score 1):

Using [a list-comprehension](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DataTypes.html#list-comprehensions) you can construct another list with just the elements you want.

```
>>> list1 = [2, "berry", "joe", 3, 5, 4, 10, "happy", "sad"]
>>> [i for i in list1 if isinstance(i, int)]
[2, 3, 5, 4, 10]
```

Alternative in case for example you also have floats and wish to keep those, too:

```
>>> list1 = [2, "berry", "joe", 3, 5, 4, 10.0, "happy", "sad"]
>>> [i for i in list1 if not isinstance(i, str)]
[2, 3, 5, 4, 10.0]
```